# Fetching a large amount of data from database

Tags: php, sql-server-2014, laravel-5.4

I have a table with more than 900,000 rows in it. When I try to fetch all rows using a PHP script, this error occurs

[image]

When I try to fetch a small amount of rows, the query runs successfully. I am using Laravel 5.4 and SQL Server 2014. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried applying pagination? How are you querying the 900k rows?

Comment: User Pagination or. You can fetch data in parts Like 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1 LIMIT 0,50'; And Increase starting limit. This functioning you can apply by ajax, But as you said 90,000 rows is this take huge amount of time. But it will work, But pagination is best option.

Comment: You need to use pagination

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination

Answer (score 0):

Check error log of your webserver, you can find there error description.

I think you have reached max_execution_time limit of php. Check that key in php.ini. You can disable that limit with setting

```
max_execution_time = 0
```

But you must understand, that fetching so many rows in one query will use a huge amount of RAM, and it's second limitation that you may reached. In such situation you can split data to chunks using multiple queries with LIMIT,OFFSET set and process that chunks one by one, having fetched at once 100000 rows for example.

Comment: it doesn't take long for the error to occur. So I don't believe increasing the execution time is going to help in any way. However, my max_execution_time is already set to 30 minutes. But you're right about the memory limit though.

Comment: It is not a good practise to use `max_execution_time = 0`. It may cause everlasting running script that you have to end manually.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, I'd advice you to retrieve a small table, then fill up the rest with an ajax request cause simple php request isn't asynchronic.